# How to create Cocoa GUI application with SwiftPM

Tags: swift, macos, swift-package-manager

I want to split my codebase into a library which I want to upload to github and an GUI application. I hope that using recently introduced SwiftPM is a good idea.

But all examples I've been able to find show creating a console application with `swift package init --type executable`.

I want to know how to create a skeleton for macOS Cocoa Application with all the pregenerated stuff like assets, storyboard and so on?

It would be great to have access to such useful thing as:

```
swift package build
swift package test
swift package update
...
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is my working solution for creating cocoa apps with SPM.

1. Create your executable version of application: `swift package init --type executable`
2. Include your packages in `Package.swift`
3. Update/fetch them: `swift package update`or `swift package fetch`
4. Create your .xcodeproj: `swift package generate-xcodeproj`
5. Open your .xcodeproj with Xcode; you'll see it as a console app.
6. Build your solution (this build will create dependencies: .frameworks, under 'Products')
7. Click the project name to see the targets
8. Add a new target by pressing `+` button below the list, and create your cocoa/gui app
9. After adding the app, click the app name on the targets list
10. Under `General` tab locate `Embedded Binaries` section.
11. Press `+` to add binaries, and select your referenced libraries.
12. Work on your cocoa app.
13. When you build, .frameworks will be embedded into .app

If you update your `packages.swift`, you should repeat above, except creating the new target; you'll just need to add it to the project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One correction: "swift init --type executable" -> "swift package init --type executable". And one question: if you add package into 'Package.swift' and execute "swift package generate-xcodeproj", the whole project will be regenerated and the cocoa/gui app will disappear from the targets list. How do add new package to 'Package.swift' without removing gui app from targets ?

Comment: Hi. There is no easy way for this. Backup your app; generate xcodeproj; add target again; replace code. Unfortunatelly, SPM + Xcode usage is limited. SPM executable + Xcode solution is a workaround. SPM + Xcode Cocoa app is workaround to a workaround.

Comment: @Andrew create a separate project (OSX or iOS) and reference the project generated by SPM as a subproject. The SPM generated project framework targets have to be slightly modified manually (search path ... etc). This way I am building my CLI with SPM and OSX and iOS app with Xcode. Updating my packages next means only slight modification of SPM generated project. It is not ideal, but it works for me. For iOS app it is necessary to change frameworks SDK to iOS SDK, otherwise, you will experience trouble while archiving your application (there is no bitcode support for OSX SDK)

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more detailed what to do if I update my `packages.swift` it doesn't seem to work for me. If I run `swift package generate-xcodeproj` a second time the updated modules do not get added in the dependencies folder. Also the folders in my Xcode project turn blue after running this command a second time.

Comment: @p0fi Did you remember to run `swift package resolve` after updating Package.swift but before running `swift package generate-xcodeproj`?